# CocoaPods linking "clang: error: no such file or directory: 'dynamic_lookup' and 'suppress'"

Tags: xcode, llvm, cocoapods

I'm getting a clang error when my project tries to link.

I can see the following flags in the Pods.debug.xcconfig and Pods.release.xcconfig

```
-undefined dynamic_lookup suppress
```

And then the error appears in issue navigator

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'dynamic_lookup'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'suppress'
```

I've tried removing the following files incase it was some generated code that was causing the issues

```
Pods/
project.xcworkspace
pods.lockfile
```

and re-running `pod install` to re-generate the workspace and config files. The error is still appearing!

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 15):

I ran into something similar today with a Cocoapod project after removing it from the podfile. for some reason my workspace still had reference to the framework (now removed) so i manually deleted the references from my Build Settings > Other Linker Flags.

I got this error afterwards and the issue was in the Other Linker Flags it had `-framework` and on the next line it had `-framework` again. When i manually deleted the framework i did not remove the corresponding `-framework` line above it so two `-framework` lines were in the adjacent rows and it couldn't find the next framework (imported from CocoaPods).

Hope this helps someone some day.

Comment: Wow great fix. I had an issue with a previous linker flag so I removed it, but didn't even think to remove `-framework` below it too.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue. Go to Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags > Debug and Release. Make sure all you have is `$(inherited)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally edited the `Other Linker Flags` list of frameworks in `Build settings`, which consequently corrupted it. So I **removed all the frameworks completely from the list** and allowed Xcode to rebuild the list automatically and voila.